# How can I create an alias for a file in bash.script and then redirect info to it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want my outputFile.txt to be generated in a bash script

I have tried to write it

```
file='/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/file'
cut -d : -f1 > file
```

but this doesnt work.
If i write /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/file when redirecting all goes ok.
What is wrong with my method of using aliases in bash

Comment: I believe you actually need to use the word `alias` some place in your example.

Comment: Aliases in bash are only expanded when they are *"the  first  word  of  a  simple command"* and only when the shell is interactive (i.e. not in scripts, unless the `expand_aliases` option is set). Both conditions make them unsuitable as targets for redirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script, `file` is a variable, not an alias. Then, you have to write `"$file"`.